# Fetching data from remote site and caching?

Tags: php, caching

I'm fetching some data from an XML page in order to do some currency calculations.
Like this: `$rates = file_get_contents("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");`

I then use that data in a function. If I include the function that does the currency conversions on every page (for example by `include("../lib/functions.php")`), will that mean that every page load re-fetches the data? Can I do some clever caching of the remote site?

Comment: Yes, it will fetch that page on every pageview, and yes, you can (and should) cache it.

Comment: I should fetch the data every 5 minutes and store it in your own database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will get that file every page load and yes you should cache the files you are getting.

A basic way of caching this file and loading it would be to create a cache version and load that instead if it is not already loaded.

```
$newCacheFile = 'eurofxref-daily.xml.cache'; //New file

if (!file_exists($cacheName)) { //Check For File
    $newCacheContent= file_get_contents('http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml'); //Get This File
    file_put_contents($newCacheFile, $newCacheContent); //Put the contents of external to new
}

$loadedFile = simplexml_load_file($newCacheFile); //Load the new file
```

You would have to check if the file created successfully etc but that shouldn't be too difficult to do yourself :)

---

If you would like to get a new version of the file, say every 24 hours then it would be possible to add this small method into the if statement `filemtime()` so we can check how old the file would be. Your code would then look like this:

```
$newCacheFile = 'eurofxref-daily.xml.cache'; //New file
$checkCacheFilePeriod = 86400; //24 hours in seconds

if (!file_exists($cacheName) || filemtime($newCacheFile) > time() + $checkCacheFilePeriod ) { //Check For File and the date it was last edited.
    $newCacheContent= file_get_contents('http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml'); //Get This File
    file_put_contents($newCacheFile, $newCacheContent); //Put the contents of external to new
}

$loadedFile = simplexml_load_file($newCacheFile); //Load the new file
```

---

Here is an article I just came across which is probably a better way to cache the created file: http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/how-to-create-a-simple-and-efficient-php-cache.

Comment: Is this caching or just storing a file? When will it be refreshed?

Comment: It is caching the file, albeit very simply and probably not the most efficient way, and  I have updated the code to check when the file was last created/modified so it will request a new one when the if statement is true.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising!

Comment: No problem, I have added an article which probably implements a better way of caching files.